# How to create multiple sidebar areas with a forloop and register_sidebars?

Tags: theme-development, register-sidebar

Im trying to create like, 8 sidebar areas using an array of page templates (like date, archive, tag ect) and then looping through the array, creating a sidebar for each value.

I thought this should work, but it only creates a sidebar for the last value in the array:

```
$widget_areas = array('single','index','category','archive','tag','taxonomy','author','date','search','attachment');
foreach($widget_areas as $area){


    register_sidebar(
         array(
        'name' => __( $area. ' Widgets' ),
        'id' => 'index',
        'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will appear on the ' . $area ),
        'before_widget' =>'<div class="widget-container">',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
        'after_widget' => '</div>'
    )
    );

}
```

The only sidebar it's creating is for the "attachment" template. What gives? Shouldnt register_sidebar run for each value in that array, creating a ton of sidebars? If I hardcode each section with register_sidebar that works, but I really dont want to repeat a bunch of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a different `id` for each sidebar or you will overwrite the same sidebar again and again. You can also just leave the `id` argument out, and WordPress will create one automatically.

Side note:

```
__( $area. ' Widgets' )
```

and

```
__( 'Widgets in this area will appear on the ' . $area )
```

… are wrong. The translation function expects a second parameter `textdomain`, and you cannot use a variable in the string that should be translated.

Use `sprintf()` with a placeholder to pass the variable, and use a context function to explain the parameter:

```
sprintf( 
    _x( 
        '%s Widgets', 
        '%s = widget area name', 
        'your_theme_textdomain' 
    ), 
    $area
)
```

Comment: I am not a smart, or careful person. I passed the $area variable to the description value but not the ID. Thanks for pointing that out and explaining the translation funtion